# How to reuse a function without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

When i use the function to check if number is positive or negative it works fine but when i try to do it again nothing happens i have to refresh the whole page to make it work again. Any help is welcome!

```js
const userNum = document.querySelector(".user-input").value;
const checkBtn = document.querySelector(".check-input");
const result = document.querySelector(".result");


function checkNum() {
    
    if (userNum > 0) {
        result.innerHTML = "Positive!!"
    }
    else if (userNum < 0) {
        result.innerHTML = "Negativeee!!"
    }
    else if (userNum < 0) {
        result.innerHTML = "Number is NULL"
    }
    else {
        result.innerHTML = "Enter a Number!!"
    }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="intro">
            <h1>A Program to Check if number is <br></h1>
            <h2>Positive, Negative or Null</h2>
            
        </div>
        <div class="check-number-type">
            <input type="text" class="user-input">
            <button onclick="checkNum()" class="check-input">Check</button>
        </div>
        <div class="show-result">
            <p class="result"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're getting the value of `.user-input` outside the function, it will always be the same. Move that into the body of the function.

Comment: @Phix ohhhhh i get it now, thanks you good sir! :)

Comment: Why do you check twice for the same condition `(userNum < 0)`? And why `return false`?

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner 2x (userNum < 0) was a typo, and for return false i honestly dont know it was trial and error hoping it would fix the issue (im still a noob at coding sry...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you say you have to "reload" the page everytime is because your code that extracts the input value was placed ***outside*** of your `checkNum` function that determines if it's positive or negative.

You only retrieve the input once, when the script starts, instead of getting a fresh copy everytime you enter the `checkNum` function.

Just move this:

```
const userNum = document.querySelector(".user-input").value;
```

Inside the `checkNum()` function.